# Class toggle doesnt work inbetween components Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hey so I have a hamburger menu that on click obviously gets an `is-active` class and that class toggles depending on the click, my problem is that it works when I'm on my home page, and then when I click to another page via `routerLink` it works but then when I click on to a second page it removes the class `is-active` as programmed but then when I click it again it doesn't add the class `is-active` but if I click it again `is-active` is applied... this also happens if Ive started on a page that isn't home Ill click the hamburger nothing happens and If I click it again the `is-active` class is applied I'm not sure what is happening here if anyone knows it would be a big help

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="nav-page">
  <a routerLink="/"><img class="img" src="../assets/img/nav-logo.svg" /></a>
  <ul (click)="navLinkClick()" class="nav-page_ul">
    <a [routerLink]="['who-we-are']"><li>who we are</li></a>
    <a [routerLink]="['our-technology']"><li>our technology</li></a>
    <a [routerLink]="['our-work']"><li>our work</li></a>
    <a [routerLin]k="['get-in-touch']"><li>contact us</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav-page-btn">
    <div (click)="hamburgerClick()" [ngClass]="wasClicked ? 'is-active' : ' '" class="hamburger hamburger--spring">
        <div class="hamburger-box">
          <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Event, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  routeHidden = true;

  title = 'app';

  wasClicked = false;

  constructor(private router: Router)
  // tslint:disable-next-line:one-line
  {}

  // tslint:disable-next-line:use-life-cycle-interface
  ngOnInit() { }

  hamburgerClick() {
    this.wasClicked = !this.wasClicked;
  }

  navLinkClick() {
    this.wasClicked = !this.wasClicked;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

So something weird that is happening is..

If I remove `(click)="hamburgerClick()"` the button works as expected on every page except the home page, but obviously I need the button work on the homepage and then also use the function to open the nav

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue but could not. However, I notice that the way you use `routerLink` in Angular 2+ is not correct. You can try this and see if it resolves the problem:

```
[routerLink]="['who-we-are']
```

You should apply this syntax to the remaining routerLinks as well.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip but it hasn't solved the issue, its very strange